# Neo4j Bulk Import CSV without unique ID

Tags: neo4j

I am having a CSV file with 10 columns which does not have unique ID.

The size of the file is about 10 GB with 40M rows.

How to import the CSV file with a unique ID generation on fly with neo4j-import

Appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Unique IDs are here to have a unique identifier for nodes, and it's mainly used to create relationships.

So `neo4j-import` really needs this value, and it's not possible to create  them 'on the fly' (otherwise it's not possible to relationship).

So you have to create this column, even if it's a dummy one for your case.

Answer (score 0):

@Sriram Krishnamurthi, I hope you have already resolved the issue. FYI, you could probably try defining labels using the following syntax. It works fine with my non-id designated .csv files. You might want to check the [official documents](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tutorial/import-tool/) for more references.

```
nodes:<YOURLABELHERE>=import\<YOURFILENAMEHERE>.csv
```